# why Cannot create an instance of class Viewmodel?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

i was making a View model for shop screen, in view model i'm using AndroidViewModel because i need to get context to use Gson library because data of shop is containing in json file

```kotlin
class ShopViewModel : AndroidViewModel(Application()) {
    private val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(getApplication<Application>().baseContext, "Store.json")
     var items by mutableStateOf(ShopItemsRepo.getItems(jsonFileString))
    fun deleteItem(shopItem: ShopItem){
        items = items.toMutableList().also {
            it.remove(shopItem)
        }
    }
}
```

and this part of code is functions of getting data from json filr with Gson library:

```kotlin
data class ShopItem(val name:String, val icon: String, val description: String, val price:Int, var isBought: Boolean) {
    fun changeIsBought(){
        this.isBought = true;
    }
}


fun shopItems(jsonFileString: String?): List<ShopItem> {
    val items = mutableListOf<ShopItem>()
    val gson = Gson()
    val listPersonType = object : TypeToken<List<ShopItem>>() {}.type

    val list: List<ShopItem> = gson.fromJson(jsonFileString, listPersonType)
    for(i in list){
        items.add(i)
    }
    return items
}

object ShopItemsRepo {
    fun getItems(jsonFileString: String?): List<ShopItem> = shopItems(jsonFileString)
}
```

and when i'm creating viewmodel in mine activity i'm getting this error:

```
val shopViewModel by viewModels<ShopViewModel>()
```

I tried use another implementations for view model,live data and etc but i didn't find nothing useful for this type of situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
class ShopViewModel : AndroidViewModel(Application()) {
```

to

```
class ShopViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
```

By calling `Application()` you were trying to instantiate an application, which doesn’t make sense. The OS provides you your own application reference. The application cannot create another one.

Instead, you should be taking the application as a constructor argument and you pass the value along to the superclass constructor, as shown in the code above. The default ViewModelProvider Factory takes care of passing the reference into the constructor.